# Ошибка 1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Tags: python, mysql, pymysql

у меня есть код:

```
id = "STEAM_1:0:464836690"
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("""SELECT `player_id` FROM `stats` WHERE `steam_id` = %s""" % (id))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    for row in rows:
        print(row[0])
```

Переменные в базе данных заданы так:

```
`player_id` int(10) NOT NULL default '0',
`steam_id` varchar(64) NOT NULL default '',
```

Но, после запуска программы у меня появляется ошибка:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':0:464836690' at line 1")
```

Answer (score 1):

выполните код:

```
id = "STEAM_1:0:464836690"
s = """id = %s""" % (id)
print(s)
```

получите:

```
id = STEAM_1:0:464836690
```

но `steam_id` - это строка

может надо так:

```
cursor.execute("""SELECT `player_id` FROM `stats` WHERE `steam_id` = '%s'""" % (id))
```

P.S.

а почему вам не нравятся f-строки?

```
cursor.execute(f"SELECT `player_id` FROM `stats` WHERE `steam_id` = '{id}'")
```

вроде как удобнее и нагляднее получается

P.P.S.

А надо ли названия полей заключать в ``? Не избыточно ли?

Comment: Спасибо, я теперь понял насколько я глупый, что писал не те кавычки)